# Ubuntu 15.10 bluetooth headset connected but not working

Tags: gnome, sound, pulseaudio, bluetooth, 15.10

Ever since I have upgraded my Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 to 15.10 (clean install), I have been facing an issue with my bluetooth headset.

The device is paired and connected but is neither listed as output device in sound settings nor in pavucontrol.

[image: connected bluetooth device and "empty" audio output list]

Has anyone any idea how I can use my headset with 15.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an update it works again. Now if I connect via bluetooth to my headset it is listed as a audio output device.

Comment: I'm getting stuttering audio after a few seconds. http://askubuntu.com/questions/750987/ubuntu-15-10-bluetooth-headset-playback-problem

Answer (score 0):

After successful connecting of the bluetooth headset, try
`sudo -i pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover`

If that then allows you to select the headset as an output device, you can make the following changes:

```
nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Comment out the following lines:

```
#.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
#load-module module-bluetooth-discover
#.endif
```

Then in:

```
nano /usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11
```

Find the following lines and add after them:

```
if [ x”$SESSION_MANAGER” != x ] ; then
/usr/bin/pactl load-module module-x11-xsmp “display=$DISPLAY session_manager=$SESSION_MANAGER” > /dev/null
fi

# Add the following lines:
/usr/bin/pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
# /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect #<-- Uncomment to automatically select headset on connection
```