# Ubuntu 15.10 bluetooth headset playback problem

Tags: sound, bluetooth

My bluetooth headset works fine with phones, windows. But when I connect it to my Ubuntu 15.10, the audio starts stuttering after a few seconds. Sometimes it skips or goes fast. In "Sounds", I have selected the "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)" profile.

I am using wifi on the same system.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`:

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142
802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:5756 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command. Are you using Wi-Fi at the same time?

Comment: @Pilot6, done. Yes, I am using WiFi at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem must be with radio interference. Wi-Fi and BT use same frequencies in 2.4 GHz band.

There is a technology called "bluetooth coexistence" that allows to avoid interference.

Unfortunately bluetooth coexistence does not work well in Broadcom wireless proprietary linux drivers.

And there is no other alternative driver for this adapter.

I am afraid there is no solution for that, except replacement of the wireless adapter.